# How can I deal or track only one face while I have detected all the faces in front of camera?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I have face recognition code which recognizes the face and show its name when I will generate the database for that, it is working well when only one face is in front of camera but I am using "FaceDetect = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;" for face detection which will detect all the faces in front of camera and I am getting bounding box around all the faces. 
Is there any way to track face of my choice among the detected all faces? 
Or can I code each bounding box face separately?
Please give me some guideline. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [example of how you can track one face](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/face-detection-and-tracking-using-the-klt-algorithm.html).  However, if you detect multiple faces, you would need some way for your program to decide, which face to track.

Alternatively, you can [track all faces](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47105-detect-and-track-multiple-faces).